# Метод overlaps для Rectangle в LibGDX не работает

Tags: java, android-studio, android-sdk, разработка-игр, libgdx

```
    posl = new Vector2(rand.nextInt(FLUC) , y);
    posr = new Vector2(posl.x - right.getWidth()  , y);

    boundsleft = new Rectangle(posl.x, posl.y, left.getWidth(),left.getHeight());
    boundsright = new Rectangle(posr.x, posr.y, right.getWidth(), right.getHeight());


 public boolean overlaps(Rectangle rb){
    return rb.overlaps(boundsleft) || rb.overlaps(boundsright);
}
```

Это строки из класса Block. Из самой логики игры :

```
for (Block tube : tubes) {
           if(tube.overlaps(Player.getRect()){
                dm.set(new OtherState(dm));
            }
```

Ну и создание Rect в классе Player

```
rect = new Rectangle(x, y, player.getWidth(),player.getHeight());
```

tubes здесь объект типа Array Block>  .dm - сокр. от display manager -- стек экранных состояний.
метод set(dm) -- объединение методов pop(dm) и push().

Comment: как понять не работает? опишите проблему подробнее

Comment: Не реагирует на событие. В теории, он должен изменять экранное состояние, но этого не происходит.

Comment: Для начала нужно понять, что именно не работает: if(tube.overlaps(Player.getRect()) или dm.set(new OtherState(dm)). Напишите перед set.dm какое-нибудь сообщение в систему с помощью System.out ... тогда будет понятнее